# Android Studio - Created a directory in External Storage but not seeing in the SDcard

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-external-storage

I am trying to create a directory under SD card using this code:

```
file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "foldername");
            if(!file.exists()){
                file.mkdirs();
                System.out.println("Directory created: " + file.getPath());
            }
```

But this ends up creating a folder under *Directory created: /storage/emulated/0/foldername*
This does not end up saving anywhere on the SD card. Does anyone know how to successfully create a directory in the SDCARD?

[SDCARD image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rS1qG.png)

Comment: `if (! file.mkdirs()) { System.out.println("Directory NOT created: " + file.getPath()) ;  return;}`

Comment: What do you mean with  SDCARD? A removable micro sd card?

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie to Android Studio. When I ran the emulator then opened the Files, it had the SDCARD folder as you can see from the image. Which is a removable one. @blackapps

Comment: Have a look at all the items returned by getExternalFilesDirs().

Answer (score 0):

Here is an object to get the "mounted" SD cards for Android 10.  Card one is the sim card and card two is the micro SD card.  When you use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() it gives you the sim card in slot one which is read-only so you can't write to that.

```
package com.example.audioplayer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.storage.StorageManager;
import android.os.storage.StorageVolume;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MountedVolumes {
    public ArrayList<String> mMountedVolumes = new ArrayList<>();

    public MountedVolumes(Context context) {
        StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager) context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);

        if (storageManager == null) {
            return;
        }

        List<StorageVolume> storageVolumes = storageManager.getStorageVolumes();

        for (StorageVolume storageVolume : storageVolumes) {
            if (storageVolume.getState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                Parcel p = Parcel.obtain();
                storageVolume.writeToParcel(p, 0);
                p.setDataPosition(0);
                p.readString();
                String path = p.readString();
                p.recycle();

                mMountedVolumes.add(path);
            }
        }
    }

    public String GetVolume(int i) {
        if (mMountedVolumes.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        if (i >= mMountedVolumes.size()) {
            return null;
        }

        return mMountedVolumes.get(i);
    }
}
```